# Showing U is a linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Check if $ U = \{f \in [\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}] \ | \ f^2 = 0\}$ where $f^2 := f \circ f $ is a linear subspace over $\mathbb{R}$ of $[\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}]$.

$[\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}]$ is the set of all mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R} $

1) The function $x \mapsto 0$ is in U, thus U is nonempty.

2) I don't understand how to show that $f +g \in U $ where $f,g \in U$. What am I supposed to add? The elements of the set or the values of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ $\forall x \in f(\mathbb{R})$ and $g(\mathbb{R})$? But then, in which order?

3) Same problem as stated in 2) for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in U$ show that $af \in U$.

Comment: 2) and 3) are both false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not. Here is a counter example :
\begin{align}
f(x) =& ~~~~~ 0 \text{ if } x \leqslant 0 \\
 & -x \text{ if } x >0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
g(x) =&  ~~~~~0 \text{ if } x \geqslant 0 \\
 & -x \text{ if } x <0
\end{align}

Then $f\circ f = g\circ g = 0$ but as $f+g = -\mathrm{id}$, then $(f+g)\circ(f+g) = \mathrm{id} \neq 0$